# TypeError: Invalid Schema Configuration: 'User' is not a valid type at path 'user.ref'

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, backend

Estoy intentando solucionar un error que he tenido al crear una variable para un proyecto y el problema es el siguiente:

El error me da en la siguiente variable:

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var FollowSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: { Type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },

    followed: { Type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Follow', FollowSchema);
```

Mensaje de la consola:

```
throw new TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${name}\` is not ` +
        ^
    
    TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `User` is not a valid type at path `user.ref`. See http://bit.ly/mongoose-schematypes for a list of valid schema types.
```